# "Matrix dimensions must agree" error when computing integral

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am having a problem in finding out the error in the following equation in MATLAB:

```
a=@(z,q)(z.^2 + q.^2);
a1=@(q) integral(@(z) a(z,q),1,10);
```

First I want to do an finite integral of `a` in `z` only, within numerical limits, lets say `1` and `10`, and then I want to plot `a1` with respect to `q`.
When I execute the above with the following command:

```
plot(linspace(0,3e8), a1(linspace(0,3e8)))
```

I got the following error:

> ```
> Matrix dimensions must agree.
>
> Error in untitled>@(z,q)(z.^2+q.^2)
>
> Error in untitled>@(z)a(z,q)
>
> Error in integralCalc/iterateScalarValued (line 314)
>     fx = FUN(t);
>
> Error in integralCalc/vadapt (line 132)
>     [q,errbnd] = iterateScalarValued(u,tinterval,pathlen);
>
> Error in integralCalc (line 75)
>     [q,errbnd] = vadapt(@AtoBInvTransform,interval);
>
> Error in integral (line 88)
>     Q = integralCalc(fun,a,b,opstruct);
>
> Error in untitled>@(q)integral(@(z)a(z,q),1,10)
> ```

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXsNp.png).

Can anyone point out the error. 
Note: I would like to have both `z` and `q` as vector

Comment: There is an "edit" link at the bottom of your question, just under the tags. Please use that to edit your question. Don't post edits as answers. I've copy-pasted your answer into the question. Go ahead and edit your question more if you like! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MATLAB function `integral` computes a single integral by default, not an array of integrals. The [option `'ArrayValued'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html#btw3ipp-6) will allow you to integrate a function that returns multiple values, such as your `a`:

```
a = @(z,q)(z.^2 + q.^2);
x = linspace(0,3e8);
y = integral(@(z)a(z,q),1,10,'ArrayValued',true);
plot(x,y)
```